# Convert specific timezone date to strtotime

Tags: php, postgresql, type-conversion

Want to convert the following tstzrange of PostgreSQL to strtotime() in PHP:-

```
["01/01/2019 00:00:00 MST","05/01/2019 00:00:00 MDT")
```

tried following things but unable to convert properly.

```
 $arrmixExtractDates     = explode( ',', $arrobjLastExtractRange[0]->getExtractRange() );
 $strRangeLowerBoundTime = strtotime( str_replace( 'MST', '', ltrim( $arrmixExtractDates[0], '[' ) ) );
 $strRangeUpperBoundTime = strtotime( str_replace( 'MDT', '', rtrim( $arrmixExtractDates[1], ')' ) ) );
```

Comment: It looks like you are trimming the `[` from the left side of the string, and `)` from the right side of the string. Is `["01/01/2019 00:00:00 MST","05/01/2019 00:00:00 MDT")` literally a string input, and not an array of two strings? Because if the bracket and parenthesis are literally in the string, then the quotes probably are too, and you'll need to remove those too.

Comment: That looks like a json encoded string. Instead of explode and trim, use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode) to turn it into an array of strings.

Comment: Instead of parsing the range directly, could you select the lower and upper elements of the range?